# Reading CloudWatch log query status in go SDK v2

Tags: go, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-sdk-go

I'm running a CloudWatch log query through the v2 SDK for Go.  I've successfully submitted the query using the StartQuery method, however I can't seem to process the results.

I've got my query ID in a variable (queryID) and am using the GetQueryResults method as follows:

```
    results, err := svc.GetQueryResults(context.TODO(), &cloudwatchlogs.GetQueryResultsInput{QueryId: queryId,})
```

How do I actually read the contents?  Specifically, I'm looking at the Status field.  If I run the query at the command line, this comes back as a string description.  According to the SDK docs, this is a bespoke type "QueryStatus", which is defined as a string with [enumerated constants](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/cloudwatchlogs@v1.15.5/types#QueryStatus).

I've tried comparing to the constant names, e.g.

```
if results.Status == cloudwatchlogs.GetQueryResultsOutput.QueryStatus.QueryStatusComplete
```

but the compiler doesn't accept this.  How do I either reference the constants or get to the string value itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QueryStatus` type is defined [in the separate types package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/cloudwatchlogs@v1.15.5/types#section-sourcefiles).  The Go SDK services are all organised this way.

```golang
import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/cloudwatchlogs/types"

if res.Status == types.QueryStatusComplete {
        fmt.Println("complete!")
}
```

Comment: Ah!  It was the types import I was missing (I think I tried the above syntax in one of my numerous attempts to get it to run...).